# Sort directory files by creation datetime in Windows filesystem

Tags: php, file, sorting, time, datecreated

How do I sort a directory by file creation, latest first in PHP 5.2?

I am on Windows 2000.

Answer (score 9):

On windows the CTime is the creation time, use the following:

```
<?php
$files = array();

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path') as $fileInfo) {    
    $files[$fileInfo->getFileName()] = $fileInfo->getCTime();
}

arsort($files);
```

After this $files will contain an array of your filenames as the keys and the ctime as the values. I chose this backwards representation due to the possibility of identical ctimes, which would cause an entry in $files to be overwritten.

#### Edit:

Updated answer to use CTime as the OP clarified he's using Windows.

Comment: This is modification Time not creation Time

Comment: Right. Did you read my first line? Most filesystems don't track creation time.

Comment: no, this won't work. rsort will *lose* the file names.

Comment: @stcony0: I updated my answer to work with windows. Please note that it will not work with *nix.

Comment: +1 for using Spl - though iterators aren't known to be this fast either ;)

Comment: Yea, but they got some nice boosts in 5.3.

Answer (score 5):

You can't for creation date on Unix system, but for change date, **but** see edit below for Windows.

Code is as follows:

```
function sortByChangeTime($file1, $file2)
{
    return (filectime($file1) < filectime($file2)); 
}
$files = glob('*');                // get all files in folder
usort($files, 'sortByChangeTime'); // sort by callback
var_dump($files);                  // dump sorted file list
```

From the Notes on the PHP Manual on [filectime](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php):

> Note: Note also that in some Unix
>   texts the ctime of a file is referred
>   to as being the creation time of the
>   file. This is wrong. There is no
>   creation time for Unix files in most
>   Unix filesystems.

See the [link in Antti's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084986/file-creation-time/2085054#2085054) for the differences in ctime, atime and mtime and decide for your Usecase which is the most suited when you are on Unix.

**Edit**: *one of the comments at the page for filectime notes that there is no change time **on Windows** and **filectime indeed returns the creation time**. I'm no pro on Windows Filesystems, but using the above is then probably your best bet. Alternatively, you can look into the COM API to get a handle on the ScriptingHost and see if you can get the Creation Time from there.*