# How to delete files from directory based on creation date in php?

Tags: php

I have a cache folder that stores html files. They are overwritten when needed, but a lot  of the time, rarely used pages are cached in there also, that just end up using space (after 5 weeks, the drive was full with over 2.7 million cache files).

Whats the best way to loop thru a directory that contains several hundreds of thousands of files, and remove files that are older than 1 day?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this in PHP? You might find a shell-scripting language more appropriate for this.

Comment: You can do all of this and more using [the Linux `find` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/589224/372950)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think you could go about this by looping through the directory with readdir and delete based on the timestamp:

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/files/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($path . $file);
        //24 hours in a day * 3600 seconds per hour
        if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 24*3600)
        {
           unlink($path . $file);
        }

    }

    closedir($handle); 
}
?>
```

The `if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 24*3600)` will select files older than 24 hours (24 hours times 3600 seconds per hour). If you wanted days, it should read for example 7*24*3600 for files older than a week.

Also, note that `filemtime` returns the time of last modification of the file, instead of creation date.

Answer (score 11):

It should be

```
if((time()-$filelastmodified) > 24*3600 && is_file($file))
```

to avoid errors for the `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: Better to check if `$file == '.' || $file == '..'` to save time from checking `is_file()` every time...

Answer (score 6):

The below function lists the file based on their creation date:

```
private function listdir_by_date( $dir ){
  $h = opendir( $dir );
  $_list = array();
  while( $file = readdir( $h ) ){
    if( $file != '.' and $file != '..' ){
      $ctime = filectime( $dir . $file );
      $_list[ $file ] = $ctime;
    }
  }
  closedir( $h );
  krsort( $_list );
  return $_list;
}
```

**Example:**

```
$_list = listdir_by_date($dir);
```

Now you can loop through the list to see their dates and delete accordingly:

```
$now = time();
$days = 1;
foreach( $_list as $file => $exp ){
  if( $exp < $now-60*60*24*$days ){
    unlink( $dir . $file );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would someone want to LOOP for getting the sorted list first and then LOOP again to delete? Doesn't make sense for overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Try [SplIterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

```
// setup timezone and get timestamp for yesterday
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); // change to yours
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', time());

// setup path to cache dir and initialize iterator
$path      = realpath('/path/to/files'); // change to yours
$objects   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));

// iterate over files in directory and delete them
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    if ($object->isFile() && ($object->getCTime() < $yesterday)) {
        // unlink($object);
        echo PHP_EOL, 'deleted ' . $object;
    }
}
```

[Creation Time is only available on Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084986/file-creation-time)

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Detele Cache Files Here */
$dir = "cache/"; /** define the directory **/

/*** cycle through all files in the directory ***/
foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {
//foreach (glob($dir.'*.*') as $file){

/*** if file is 24 hours (86400 seconds) old then delete it ***/
if (filemtime($file) < time() - 3600) { // 1 hour
    unlink($file);
    }
}
```

I am using this, hope it helps. Also, I updated this on 13-02-2023, visit: https://www.arnlweb.com/forums/server-management/efficient-php-code-for-deleting-files-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

just to note Gordon's time comparison (see above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205833/1875965) is the only correct one when comparing to 'days' rather than '24 hours', as not all days have 24 hours (summertime/wintertime etc).

E.g. use

```
// setup timezone and get timestamp for yesterday
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); // change as appropriate
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', time());
```

when comparing the file date.

This may not be a big issue, but can lead to unexpected behaviour when you're working with weeks/months etc. I found it best to stick to using the above method as it'll make any process involving dates/times consistent and avoid confusion.

Also check what the timezone is for the file dates, as sometimes the default for PHP differs from the system timezone.

Kind regards, Sandra.

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pathfromRoot/';

$files = array_slice(scandir($directory), 2);
foreach($files as $file)
{
    // $extension      = substr($file, -3, 3); 
    // if ($extension == 'jpg') // in case you only want specific files deleted
    // {
    $stat = stat($directory.$file);
    $filedate = date_create(date("Y-m-d", $stat['ctime']));
    $today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
    $days = date_diff($filedate, $today, true);
    // dd($days);
    if ($days->days > 180) 
    { 
        unlink($directory.$file);
    }
     // } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By changing @pawel's solution I created function below.
At first i forgot to add "path" to file name, which take my half hour to find out.

```
public function deleteOldFiles ($hours=24) {
    $path='cache'.DS;
    if ( $handle = opendir( $path ) ) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $filelastmodified = filemtime($path.$file);
            if((time()-$filelastmodified) > 24*3600 && is_file($path.$file))
            {
                unlink($path.$file);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```