# php script to delete files older than 24 hrs, deletes all files

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I wrote this php script to delete old files older than 24 hrs,
but it deleted all the files including newer ones:

```
<?php
  $path = 'ftmp/';
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ((time()-filectime($path.$file)) < 86400) {  
           if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $file)) {
              unlink($path.$file);
           }
        }
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: What OS are you using this on? Win32 or Unix/Linux?

Comment: shouldn't it be > 86400?

Comment: It's on a Linux system.

I see my error. But why did it delete the old files too?

Comment: Because something is changing the metadata of the files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete files from directory based on creation date in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205738/how-to-delete-files-from-directory-based-on-creation-date-in-php)

Comment: Be careful with your trailing slashes too. If `$path` doesn't have a trailing slash this code will fail.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
(time()-filectime($path.$file)) < 86400
```

If the current time and file's changed time are *within* 86400 seconds of each other, then...

```
 if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $file)) {
     unlink($path.$file);
 }
```

I think that may be your problem. Change it to > or >= and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 70):

```
<?php

/** define the directory **/
$dir = "images/temp/";

/*** cycle through all files in the directory ***/
foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {

/*** if file is 24 hours (86400 seconds) old then delete it ***/
if(time() - filectime($file) > 86400){
    unlink($file);
    }
}

?>
```

You can also specify file type by adding an extension after the * (wildcard) eg

For jpg images use: `glob($dir."*.jpg")`

For txt files use: `glob($dir."*.txt")`

For htm files use: `glob($dir."*.htm")`

Answer (score 8):

1. You want `>` instead.
2. Unless you're running on Windows, you want `filemtime()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php   
$dir = getcwd()."/temp/";//dir absolute path
$interval = strtotime('-24 hours');//files older than 24hours

foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) 
    //delete if older
    if (filemtime($file) <= $interval ) unlink($file);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested two methods to compare the speed. Option A was repeatedly about 50% faster. I ran this on a folder with about 6000 files.

**Option A**

```
$path='cache/';
$cache_max_age=86400; # 24h
if($handle=opendir($path)){
    while($file=readdir($handle)){
        if(substr($file,-6)=='.cache'){
            $filectime=filectime($path.$file);
            if($filectime and $filectime+$cache_max_age<time()){
                unlink($path.'/'.$file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option B**

```
$path='cache/';
$cache_max_age= 86400; # 24h
foreach(glob($path."*.cache") as $file){
    $filectime=filectime($file);
    if($filectime and $filectime+$cache_max_age<time()){
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

It also checks whether a file creation time was returned. On some systems, there are problems with returning the creation time. Therefore I wanted to make sure that it does not delete all files if the system does not return a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

working fine

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
$timer = 300;
$filetime = filectime($file)+$timer;
$time = time();
$count = $time-$filetime;
    if($count >= 0) {
      if (preg_match('/\.png$/i', $file)) {
        unlink($path.'/'.$file);
      }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$path = '/cache/';
// 86400 = 1day

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( (integer)(time()-filemtime($path.$file)) > 86400 && $file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
                unlink($path.$file);
                echo "\r\n the file deleted successfully: " . $path.$file;
        } 
     }
}
```