# PHP - Clear content in txt file every 24 hours

Tags: php, file

I have a text file, that stores chat log and I want the content to be cleared automaticly by the server when the clock is `00:00:00.000`, or let’s say at a certain time, so that it’s cleared every 24 hours. I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126191/php-script-to-delete-files-older-than-24-hrs-deletes-all-files) but I want the server to automaticly **clear** not delete the txt file.

Comment: Just replace the code in the link you've given us, with a replacing function. Or, in SQL you can use an UPDATE and replace with the blank content or content of your choice.

Comment: Well, I found another solution, deleting the file if 24H old, then replace with a new, empty

Comment: But I don't know how though, and I don't want to delete every file.

Comment: You can just write "nothing" to file using `fwrite` with the `w` switch or `file_put_contents`. Easy as pie. But CRON seems to be the answer to do this every X-amount of time.

Comment: one.com servers, I have Windows 8.1 though

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to run automatically you can set up a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Or if you are on Windows use the [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Using this you can run for example a php file on a specific time using:

```
php -f /path/to-your/file
```

An example of a line in the crontab will look like:

```
0  0  *  *  *  php -f /path/to-your/file
```

The above will run the script every day at 00:00

Comment: German? I wonder, isn't there anything simpler?

Comment: Ooh nice command there, but where do I type it (nOOb)

Comment: where I put the time?

Answer (score 0):

create a php file **/path/to/your/php/script.php**

```
<?php

    $log_file = /path/to/your/log/file.txt;

    file_put_contents($log_file, '');

?>
```

now set cronjob on your server

```
0  0  *  *  *  php -f /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

and you are done...

**EDIT:** if you don't want to use cronjob, then you can use this method

create a file name **clear_logs.php**

```
<?php

    $_00hours = date('His');


    if($_00hours == '000000'){

        $log_file = '/path/to/your/log/file.txt';

        file_put_contents($log_file, '');

    }

?>
```

Now include this file in your website files

**Note:** Second method is not recommended as user must come to website at **00:00:00** so that the statements under **if condition** can be executed