# Delete a file having specific age in PHP

Tags: php, file, time, delete-file

I have a lot of files in a directory. And I want to delete the file(s) which is/are older than 10 hours (created at least 10 hours ago). How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: this will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126191/php-script-to-delete-files-older-than-24-hrs-deletes-all-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for you

```
<?php
    $dir = '/path/to/my/dir';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $cnt = count($files);
    $deadline = strtotime('now')-36000;
    for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i)
    {
        $files[$i] = $dir.'/'.$files[$i];
        if(!is_file($files[$i]) || $files[$i] == '.' || 
            $files[$i] == '..' || filemtime($files[$i]) <= $deadline)
            unset($files[$i]);
        else
            unlink($files[$i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has function `filemtime()` which return the last modified date.

```
if ((time() - filemtime($filename)) > 60 * 60 * 10) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```