# Loop through series of folders and check how old the folder

Tags: php, loops, filesystems, directory

I am making a Cron that will delete a folder older than 15days. I already made a function to delete the folder and it's content, what I don't have is to loop inside a folder then check each folder's age then if that is 15days old or above I will executue my delete function.

I want to loop inside `public/uploads`

in my `uploads` directory I store folders with content ex.

```
public/
  uploads/
      Test/
      Test2/
```

I want to check how old those folder then delete it by calling

```
function Delete($path)
{
 if (is_dir($path) === true)
 {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
    }

    return rmdir($path);
 }

 else if (is_file($path) === true)
 {
    return unlink($path);
 }

 return false;
}
```

How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/8965778/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3126191/ - one of those is probably a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php). This lets you determine the last modified date of a file (or directory). That in combination with the [various directory functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) will allow you to loop through them and check their dates.

This is something mocked up off the top of my head to give you a rough idea of *how* you may go about this:

```
$dir = '/path/to/my/folders';
$folders = scandir($dir);
foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    $lastModified = filemtime($folder);
    // Do a date comparison here and call your delete if necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I exactly need :) How the I convert $lastModified to a time format and compare it if it is greater than 15days?

Comment: We can't do everything for you here -- try doing some research and come back if you get stuck. *Hint: Search stack overflow for "php compare dates"*

Comment: when I tried to echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lastModified); it gives me 2015-07-28 14:02:40 2015-07-28 15:02:01 1970-01-01 01:00:00 why is it giving me 3 dates? where I only have 1 folder inside public/uploads/

Comment: ...it is inside of a foreach loop. Try dumping out `$folders` and see what it is returning. Might be including the `..` and `.` directories.

Comment: There is indeed a file inside a diretory, what if I only want to get the last datemodified of the folder the I am looping into without touching the files inside it?

Comment: $folders has 3 items? I only have 1 folder in that direcotry

Comment: Pass just the path of that folder then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84474/discussion-between-joene-floresca-and-cillosis).