# How would i delete all the images in a folder that are 24 hours old or older

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete files from directory based on creation date in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205738/how-to-delete-files-from-directory-based-on-creation-date-in-php)

How would i delete all the images in a folder that are 24 hours old or older in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$imagePattern = "/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tiff)$/";
$directory = ".";

if (($handle = opendir($directory)) != false) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) != false) {
        $filename = "$directory/$file";
        if (strtotime("-24 hours") <= filemtime($filename) && preg_match($imagePattern, $filename)) {
            unlink($filename);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Still might need $directory before $file in the unlink(). Would be easier with glob() eventually.

Comment: It will also need to match images - as in the question - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're on *nix, punt it off to the shell and [find](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=man+find+unix):

```
shell_exec('find /path/to/your/directory -mtime +0 -exec rm -f {} \;');
```

Answer (score 1):

combination of:

to check time https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

to delete https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to use a naming convention that includes a unix timestamp if you have control over that.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec('find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;');
```

Comment: Won't work on servers without `find` in the search path, including Windows machines and locked down Linux machines.