# The correct way to delete all files older than 2 days in PHP

Tags: php, file, caching

Just curious:

```
$files = glob(cacheme_directory() . '*');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filemtime = filemtime($file);
    if (time() - $filemtime >= 172800) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

I just want to make sure if the code is correct or not. Thanks.

Comment: please use the search function before asking http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+files+older+php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete files from directory based on creation date in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205738/how-to-delete-files-from-directory-based-on-creation-date-in-php)

Comment: It's not duplicate. The one I wrote is simple and I only want to ask if this is correct or not which is a much easier question.

Comment: @JimThio asking whether it works is not a real question. Write a UnitTest or simply try it in a test folder. And yes, this is a duplicate of the linked one. It covers exactly the same grounds. And there is more duplicates in the linked search.

Comment: Well I got nice suggestions on how to improve it at least.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You should add an [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) check, because sub-directories could reside in the the directory you're checking.

Also, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8965788/420747) suggests, you should replace the pre-calculated seconds with a more expressive notation.

```
$files = glob(cacheme_directory() . '*');
$threshold = strtotime('-2 day');
  
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        if ($threshold >= filemtime($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could also use the `DirectoryIterator`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548138/420747). In this simple case it doesn't really offer any advantages, but it would be OOP way.

Comment: Works like a charm, but why u people always exclude brackets { }
I love them :D i can't do without them.
Otherwise code is naked

Comment: You really need to add the backets. This code is not readable and tidy.

Comment: I wrote this answer back when I had a short-lived liaison with Python. Brackets have been added. ;)

Comment: If you are on php5.3+, check Maksim.T's answer.

Comment: A small improvement can be made to calculate the cutoff-time once and comparing against that in the loop, instead of calculating the difference between to datetimes in the loop every time.

Answer (score 77):

The easiest way is by using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php):

```
if (file_exists($folderName)) {
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folderName) as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($fileInfo->isFile() && time() - $fileInfo->getCTime() >= 2*24*60*60) {
            unlink($fileInfo->getRealPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but is slighlty faster if you just calculate time() and 2*24*60*60 once before the while loop and use variables in the loop.

Comment: I'd just like to say thanks. This honestly should be the chosen answer.

Comment: works great and learned about the DirectoryIterator which is awesome!

Comment: Is the `isDot()` check necessary?  Won't the `isFile()` check suffice for that?

Comment: Note: If your'e using WIndows `getCTime()` is the file creation time, so you might want to use `getMTime()` if you want to use last modified time instead of creation time.

Answer (score 21):

[FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) is a more simple and modern way. `FilesystemIterator` has an advantage over `DirectoryIterator` in that it ignores the virtual directories `.` and `..`.

Using directory `logs` as an example:

```
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('logs');
$threshold = strtotime('-2 day');
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $file) {
    if ($threshold >= $file->getCTime()) {
        unlink('logs/'.$file->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I reckon this is much tidier and easier to read and modify.

```
$expire = strtotime('-7 DAYS');

$files = glob($path . '/*');

foreach ($files as $file) {

    // Skip anything that is not a file
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        continue;
    }

    // Skip any files that have not expired
    if (filemtime($file) > $expire) {
        continue;
    }

    unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: Some people don't prefer guard clause...

Comment: filemtime($file) < $expire I suppose?

Comment: Guards are risky if you are deleting files. I always double check before deleting

Answer (score 6):

```
/* Delete Cache Files Here */
$dir = "cache/"; /** define the directory **/

/*** cycle through all files in the directory ***/
foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {
//foreach (glob($dir.'*.*') as $file){

/*** if file is 24 hours (86400 seconds) old then delete it ***/
if (filemtime($file) < time() - 172800) { // 2 days
    unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

I updated this code in 2023, check it out: https://www.arnlweb.com/forums/server-management/efficient-php-code-for-deleting-files-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-the-right-way/

Answer (score 4):

Looks correct to me. I'd just suggest you replace `172800` with `2*24*60*60` for clarity.

Comment: or just add `// 2 days` beside it, for even more clarity

Comment: Or just create constants at the beginning of your project like DAY_IN_SECONDS, WEEK_IN_SECONDS, etc. lol

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to do it recursively.

```
function remove_files_from_dir_older_than_x_seconds($dir,$seconds = 3600) {
    $files = glob(rtrim($dir, '/')."/*");
    $now   = time();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_file($file)) {
            if ($now - filemtime($file) >= $seconds) {
                echo "removed $file<br>".PHP_EOL;
                unlink($file);
            }
        } else {
            remove_files_from_dir_older_than_x_seconds($file,$seconds);
        }
    }
}

remove_files_from_dir_older_than_x_seconds(dirname(__file__).'/cache/', (60 * 60 * 24 * 1) ); // 1 day
```

Comment: Excellent you save my time, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that you'll run into problems if you have a very large number of files in the directory.

If you think this is likely to affect you, consider using a lower level approach such as [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php).

Comment: What kinds of problems might we be running into?

Comment: @vertigoelectric out of memory problems

Answer (score 2):

@maksim-t answer can be improved a bit:

1. Calculate the oldest "allowed" from the start, instead of calculating it on every iteration.
2. Use Modification time, instead of creation time, because otherwise you may remove files, that were updated recently.
3. Use getPathname instead of getFilename, so that there will be not need for concatenation of the path.

```php
#Initiate iterator
$fileSI = new FilesystemIterator($this->files);
#Get the oldest allowed time
$oldest = time() - ($maxFileAge * 86400);
#Iterate the files
foreach ($fileSI as $file) {
    #Check time
    if ($file->getMTime() <= $oldest) {
        #Remove the file
        @unlink($file->getPathname());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** It deletes old files.
 *  @param string $dir Directory
 *  @param int $secs Files older than $secs seconds
 *  @param string $pattern Files matching $pattern
 */
function delete_oldfiles($dir,$secs,$pattern = "/*")
{
    $now = time();
    foreach(glob("$dir$pattern") as $f) {
      if (is_file($f) && ($now - filemtime($f) > $secs)) unlink($f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(time()-filectime($path.$file)) < 172800 //2 days
```

If the current time and file are changed time are within 172800 seconds of each other, then.

```
 if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $file)) {
     unlink($path.$file);
 }
```

Well, if its there still any confusion you just need to change the operator from the first line of code.