# How to delete files in a folder on hosting after 2 hours interval

Tags: php, image, file, hosting

Please help me...i want to delete the image files generated by user login on my website....The files are saved in a folder of website.So i basically want all the files of that particular folder to get deletes after every 2 hours interval

Comment: possible duplicate of [The correct way to delete all files older than 2 days in PhP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965778/the-correct-way-to-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+all+files+older+php

Answer (score 3):

Use cron job. Tell it to list the files, and if they are older than 2 hours, use unlink() to remove them.

```
$dir = "/var/www/userimages/";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if ((time() - filemtime($file)) > strtotime('2 hours')) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you cannot use cron to schedule your script, call the function given by Matt Gibson at the beginning of your PHP controller (do you use a controller didn't it?) or call it from your login script.