# How to delete files created through POST in PHP after Expiry Time

Tags: php, post

If I were to create a board like 4Chan.
How could I make it so a post that would expire and be perm. deleted after 24 hours?

Here is what I have so far for saving the file:

```
    <?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: What you "have so far" is just copy and pasted code, not pretty good code mind you. You need to think about your actual goal (uploaded images != posts), and google a bit further.

Comment: Do you have a database to store information about the posts?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have added, I suspect you are looking for a file based approach.

Nevertheless, as stated in the comments, it would also be good to have a database such as MYSQL to store your data.

Additionally, in your tags and question you don't specify important information such as: on which operating system.

Neverthess less, based on your code that your creating files, here are resources related to deleting files created after X amount of time:

- [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/
- [How to delete files older than X hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249578/how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-hours)
- [The correct way to delete all files older than 2 days in PhP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965778/the-correct-way-to-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-in-php)

And also related to scheduled tasks and cron:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/
- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569