# delete expired file with php code

Tags: php

Can PHP delete expired files?
I tried with my code like this,
but php delete all the files in the folder
my code :

```
         $dir    = 'images/';
         if (is_dir($dir)) { if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
         if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) { 
         $file_date = date ("d-m-Y", filemtime($dir."/".$file));
         echo $file_date ;
         $file_ch_exp_date = strtotime( $file_date);
         //echo $file_ch_exp_date ;
         echo "<br>";

         if(time() > $file_ch_exp_date) {
            unlink($dir."/".$file); 
         }
            }                
        }            
        closedir($dh);
        }
        }
```

I have in my folder file that I want to delete :

1.jpg 19.06.2017

2.jpg 19.06.2017

3.jpg 19.06.2017

I don't want to delete

**ok.jpg 28.06.2017**

Comment: The filemtime() function returns the last time the file content was modified. 

So it refer to a past date and I think that for all file the if statment return true and delete it.

Comment: time() > $file_ch_exp_date seems to be counter-intuitive. You want to remove older files than the expiry date, so you need to do an inverse check of time() < $file_ch_exp_date

Comment: As Osama already pointed out, filemtime returns the last time a file was modified. If you want to check the creation date, then you will need filectime, note the c instead of m in the name. It means creation instead of modification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The correct way to delete all files older than 2 days in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965778/the-correct-way-to-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this bit of code it may help

```
      $files = glob(cacheme_directory()."*");
      $now   = time();

      foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_file($file)) {
          if ($now - filemtime($file) >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 2) { // 2 days
            unlink($file);
          }
        }
      }
```

you can checkout the answer over here its for refrence  [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548138/8164643)

Comment: Thank you for this it work , I appreciate it very much