# Sorting files by creation/modification date in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [File creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084986/file-creation-time)

In PHP, how to retrieve the files contained into a folder sorted by creation date (or any other sorting mechanism)?

[According to the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), the *readdir()* function:

> The filenames are returned in the
> order in which they are stored by the
> filesystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

save their information to an array, sort the array and then loop the array

```
if($h = opendir($dir)) {
  $files = array();
  while(($file = readdir($h) !== FALSE)
    $files[] = stat($file);

  // do the sort
  usort($files, 'your_sorting_function');

  // do something with the files
  foreach($files as $file) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's my solution:

```
$fileList = array();
$files = glob('home/dir/*.txt');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileList[filemtime($file)] = $file;
}
ksort($fileList);
$fileList = array_reverse($fileList, TRUE);
print_r($fileList);
```

output is like this:

```
array(
    (int) 1340625301 => '/home/dir/file15462.txt',
    (int) 1340516112 => '/home/dir/file165567.txt',
    (int) 1340401114 => '/home/dir/file16767.txt'
)
```

Then with "foreach" loop take the file you need.

Comment: Lets hope none of your files get modified within the same second of unix time.

Comment: I replaced the foreach body line with:
$fileList[filemtime($file).$file] = $file;
It solves the issue salathe mentions. I have the impression that this key conversion to string also makes ksort much faster for my 300k files.

Comment: Will not work when there are two files with the SAME creation date :-/

Comment: There is a capital 'L' missing in the last line. 
Should be: 
print_r($fileList); 
Apologies for posting it here but it says: "The suggested edit cue is full"

Answer (score 4):

You can store the files in an array, where the key is the filename and the value is the value to sort by (i.e. creation date) and use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on that array.

```
$files = array(
    'file1.txt' => 1267012304,
    'file3.txt' => 1267011892,
    'file2.txt' => 1266971321,
);
asort($files);
var_dump(array_keys($files));
# Output:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "file2.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "file3.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "file1.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Heh, not even the great [**DirectoryIterator**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) can do that out of the box. Sigh.

There seems to be a pretty powerful script to do all that referenced here: [**preg_find**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php#75132). I've never worked with it but it looks good.

```
sorted in by filesize, in descending order?
$files = preg_find('/./', $dir,
  PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE| PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC |
  PREG_FIND_SORTFILESIZE|PREG_FIND_SORTDESC);

$files=array_keys($files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scandir()` to read the contents of the directory into an array, then use `fileatime()` or `filectime()` to see each file's access or creation time, respectively. Sorting the array from here shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score -2):

use [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute command on os-level? on a linux/unix box this might work;

```
$output=shell_exec('ls -t1');
```