# List directory filenames by file word count

Tags: php

I'd like to,

1. Check the word count for a folder full of text files.
2. Output a list of the files arranged by word count in the format - FILENAME is WORDCOUNT

I know str_word_count is used to get individual wordcounts for files but I'm not sure how to rearrange the output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038896/arrange-files-by-creation-or-modification-with-php/3038961#3038961).

```
<?php
    $files = array();
    $it = new DirectoryIterator("/tmp");
    $it->rewind();
    while ($it->valid()) { 
        $count = str_word_count(file_get_contents($it->getFilename()));
        $files[sprintf("%010d", $count) . $it->getFilename()] =
            array($count, $it->getFilename()); 
        $it->next();
    }

    ksort($files);
    foreach ($files as $tup) {
        echo sprintf("%s is %d\n", $tup[1], $tup[0]);
    }
```

**EDIT** It would be more elegant to have `$file`'s key be the file name and `$file`'s value be the word count and then sort by value.

Comment: It outputs the files, but doesn't arrange them by wordcount

Comment: @user Are you sure? The initial version had a few errors I hopefully corrected.

Comment: I think the probem is that ksort arranges by key, which in this case is filename?

Comment: @user No, the key is the count. The filename is appended to the count so that the key is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use php but I would

1. create array to hold filename and
   wordcount
2. read through the folder full of text
   files and for each save the filename
   and wordcount to the array
3. sort the array by wordcount
4. output the array

To store the information (#2) I would put the information into a 2D array. There is more information about 2D arrays [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php17p4.html) at Free PHP Tutorial. Thus array[0][0] would equal the name of the first file and array[0](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php17p4.html) would be the wordcount. array[1](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php17p4.html)[0] and array[1](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php17p4.html) would be the for the next file.

To sort the array (#3) you can use the tutorial [firsttube.com](http://firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/).

The to output I would do a loop through the array and output the first and second location.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); ++$i) {
    print the filename ($array[$i][0]) and wordcount ($array[$i][1])
}
```

Comment: My problem is step 3, how do I store the name of the file and the count together for output later?

Comment: @user201140 - just added more information to the answer. If you have anymore questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the iterator-style approach (yet still do essentially the same as [Artefacto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086851/list-directory-filenames-by-file-word-count/3086900#3086900)'s answer) then something like the following would suffice.

```
$dir_it = new FilesystemIterator("/tmp");
// Build array iterator with word counts
$arr_it = new ArrayIterator();
foreach ($dir_it as $fileinfo) {
    // Skip non-files
    if ( ! $fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
    $fileinfo->word_count = str_word_count(file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname()));
    $arr_it->append($fileinfo);
}
// Sort by word count descending
$arr_it->uasort(function($a, $b){
    return $b->word_count - $a->word_count;
});

// Display sorted files and their word counts
foreach ($arr_it as $fileinfo) {
    printf("%10d %s\n", $fileinfo->word_count, $fileinfo->getFilename());
}
```

---

*Aside*: If the files are particularly large (read: loading each one entirely into memory just to count the words is too much) then you could loop over the file line-by-line (or byte-by-byte if you really wanted to) with the [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject).