# Displaying images from folder in php

Tags: php, image

Hello I have this code to show image from folder in php :

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/galerija/accomodation/');
while($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        echo '<img src="galerija/accomodation/'.$file.'" rel="colorbox" />';
    }
}
```

and it's working everthing is fine but how can I set to show folder sorter by name or something, because I really need to sort that images and this script show's only random images.Thank you.

Comment: Store file names in an array, sort the array and then display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find your answer here:
[Sorting files by creation/modification date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325650/sorting-files-by-creation-modification-date-in-php)

There are other similar posts where you could get another usefull function for sorting.

So that your code should look something like this:

```
if($h = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/galerija/accomodation/')) {
  $files = array();
  while(($file = readdir($h) !== FALSE){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
       $files[] = stat($file);
    }
  }

  // do the sort
  usort($files, 'sortByName');

  // do something with the files
  foreach($files as $file) {
            echo '<img src="galerija/accomodation/'.$file.'" rel="colorbox" />';
  }
}

//some functions you can use to sort the files
//sort by change time
//you can change filectime with filemtime and have a similar effect
function sortByChangeTime($file1, $file2){
    return (filectime($file1) < filectime($file2)); 
}

function sortByName{
    return (strcmp($file1,$file2)); 
}
```

Comment: "syntax error, unexpected T_IF in "path to php" on line 5" how can i fix this

Comment: my last edit should do the trick, there was a semicolon that do not belong there, my fault

Answer (score 1):

Using [glob](https://www.php.net/glob) and [sort](http://nl.php.net/sort):

```
$files = glob("*.jpg");
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: No. I will not write your code for you, you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should first store the images (`$files`) to an array, for example `$aImages[] = $file`. The you can use several sort functions from PHP to sort your array. `asort(), usort(), sort()...`. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php