# php include file with newest date

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to make a sort of blog with php and I want to include the 5 newest files in an other directory by modification time.

I can inculde them all one by one each time I have made a new file, but it would be nice if I can just include the newest 5.

Because i don't want to put the modification date in the file name I really don't know how to do it.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Check out scandir() and filemtime().  http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php    http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: Do you really mean `include`, as in these are PHP files? If so, this sounds like you're mixing your content with your implementation. Maybe consider using a database of some sort...

Comment: @IMSoP I really mean include, I want them to be php files. It's not really a blog or something. It is actuallt for myself. I have a lot of websites (for school) and because I have a lot of files I just want the newest 5 so I can easely see with which site i'm busy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "/path/to/directory"; //the directory path 

$latest5files = array();    //array for latest 5 files to be stored

$d = dir($path);

while ((false !== ($entry = $d->read())) || count($latest5files) < 5) 
{
     $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";

     if ((is_file($filepath))) 
     {
         $latest_filename[] = $entry;
     }
}
```

Then include the whole files in the array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($latest5files); $i++)
{
    include $latest5files[ $i ];
}
```

Comment: now i have this and the directory i want it in is "sites", but it won't work. am i doing something wrong? `<?php $path = "sites/"; //the directory path 

$latest5files = array();    //array for latest 5 files to be stored

$d = dir($path);

while ((false !== ($entry = $d->read())) || count($latest5files) < 5) 
{
     $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";

     if ((is_file($filepath))) 
     {
         $latest_filename[] = $entry;
     }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($latest5files); $i++)
{
    include $latest5files[ $i ];
}
?>`

Comment: @Moreno__R change `sites/` to `/sites`. Because script tries to find `sites//filename.txt` which is a non-existing url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list files with array for eg.

```
$a[1234567890] = 'file1.php';

arsort($a);

foreach(array_slice($input, 0, 5) as $fTime => $file):
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

You can check the file modification time with this functions.

Read the file sort it with that time.

More info on

[Sorting files by creation/modification date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325650/sorting-files-by-creation-modification-date-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to get last access info of all files in a directory

```
    $p = "path";


    $a = scandir($p);


    foreach($a as $f){

    $last_access = fileatime($p."/".$f);

    }
```