# How to sort file name from a folder order by create date by php?

Tags: php, sorting, directory

How to sort file name from a folder **order by create date** by php?

```
$filesname = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../tmp/20120123/';
foreach(glob($filesname) as $files){
    echo $files.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort files by date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Creation Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084986/file-creation-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function I wrote for just such a task:

```
// Constants to make usage more reader-friendly
define('DIR_SORT_NAME',  1);
define('DIR_SORT_SIZE',  2);
define('DIR_SORT_ATIME', 3);
define('DIR_SORT_MTIME', 4);
define('DIR_SORT_CTIME', 5);

function readdir_sorted_array ($dir, $sortCol = DIR_SORT_NAME, $sortDir = SORT_ASC) {

  // Validate arguments
  $dir = rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $dir), '/');
  $sortCol = (int) ($sortCol >= 1 && $sortCol <= 5) ? $sortCol : 1;
  $sortDir = ($sortDir == SORT_DESC) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;
  $name = $size = $aTime = $mTime = $cTime = $table = array();

  // Open the directory, return FALSE if we can't
  if (!is_dir($dir) || (!$dp = opendir($dir))) return FALSE;

  // Fetch a list of files in the directory and get stats
  for ($i = 0; ($file = readdir($dp)) !== FALSE; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($file, array('.','..'))) {
      $path = "$dir/$file";
      $row = array('name'=>$file,'size'=>filesize($path),'atime'=>fileatime($path),'mtime'=>filemtime($path),'ctime'=>filectime($path));
      $name[$i] = $row['name'];
      $size[$i] = $row['size'];
      $aTime[$i] = $row['atime'];
      $mTime[$i] = $row['mtime'];
      $cTime[$i] = $row['ctime'];
      $table[$i] = $row;
    }
  }

  // Sort the results
  switch ($sortCol) {
    case DIR_SORT_NAME:
      array_multisort($name, $sortDir, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_SIZE:
      array_multisort($size, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_ATIME:
      array_multisort($aTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_MTIME:
      array_multisort($mTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_CTIME:
      array_multisort($cTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
  }

  // Return the result
  return $table;

}
```

Hopefully usage is fairly self-explanatory.