# Get all the files in directory with the created date in an array

Tags: php, file, date, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084986/file-creation-time)

I want to get all the files in a directory along with its date of creation in array.

I saw the `scandir` function, but it returns even the directory which I don't want. I also figured out that `filemtime($filename)` function can return the file created date. Just not able to put it together.

Comment: Short answer: File creation time does not exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in these days of PHP > 5 you should be using the [provided classes](http://www.php.net/spl) for this kind of thing. For this particular task you should be using the [FilesystemIterator](http://www.php.net/filesystemiterator) for example:-

```
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator('D:/dev/');
foreach($iterator as $fileInfo){
    if($fileInfo->isFile()){
        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getCTime());
        echo $fileInfo->getFileName() . " file Created " . $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') .  "<br/>\n";
    }
    if($fileInfo->isDir()){
        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getMTime());
        echo $fileInfo->getFileName() . " dir Modified " . $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') . "<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

Here `$fileInfo` is an instance of [SplFileInfo](http://www.php.net/splfileinfo) which can give you all the information about a file or directory you could ever want.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        echo filemtime($file)."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$file;
     }

    closedir($handle); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get all the files and sub-directory of main directory

then use [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) function of php.

If you want to access specific extensions file please use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function of php

Here is the example :

[How to get only images using scandir in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226519/use-php-scandirdir-and-get-only-images)

I hope this helps.